# How to manage Scrollview Height according to textview content Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, textview, uiscrollview, scrollview

I am trying to manage scrollview height according to textview content height with other view.

Code:

```
struct TextviewWithScrollview: View {
    @State private var textStyle = UIFont.TextStyle.body
    @State private var textForTextView = "fdgfhjdsgfdhsgfdsfg dsfg dsfgdsfh fh sf hdsjklf dhsjkfhsdjkfdhsjkfadhsfkds fdshfjkldsh fjkldsh fdshfdshfdsfhsfdsfh sf ewf g iuf herjkdsjkjvdhsvdshvdsv dshv ds vads vds hvsdvjkds vds hviuds  vhv disu ghdisuv g"
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    TextView(isEditable: .constant(false), text:  .constant(textForTextView), textStyle:$textStyle, didStartEditing: .constant(false),placeHolderText:"")
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Button("Top") {
                    }
                    Button("Middle") {
                        
                    }
                    Button("Bottom") {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isEditable:Bool
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle
    @Binding var didStartEditing: Bool
    var placeHolderText: String = ""
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        textView.dataDetectorTypes = .all
        textView.textColor = .white
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($text)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var text: Binding<String>
        
        init(_ text: Binding<String>) {
            self.text = text
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.text.wrappedValue = textView.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output without Scrollview:**

[image: Output Without Scrollview]

**Output With Scrollview:**

[image: Output With Scrollview]

Can someone please explain to me how to manage Scrollview Height according to textview content with other's views. I've tried to implement by above but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw if you don't need to support iOS 13, you should use [TextEditor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor)

Comment: Not really clear what do you want to achieve. What if text grows out of screen? Should buttons be always on screen? in center? Why do you use UITextView, is it a required, restriction? Would you elaborate more on goals.

Comment: @Asperi my goal is full screen scroll with textview and with other views. because when i'm using textview with scrollview the textview not working properly but when i'm not using scrollview the textview working fine but other views scrolling off. so can you please help me how to achieve full screen scrollview with textview?

Comment: @aheze but in TextEditor not supported the Highlighting the url.

Comment: is it possible to manage Scrollview Height? @Asperi

Comment: Marked as duplicate based on accepting a plagiarized answer from that question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you would like to achieve:

[image]

To get this result, embed the ScrollView in a GeometryReader and size the TextView with a frame. Like so:

```
struct TextviewWithScrollview: View {
@State private var textStyle = UIFont.TextStyle.body
@State private var textForTextView = "fdgfhjdsgfdhsgfdsfg dsfg dsfgdsfh fh sf hdsjklf dhsjkfhsdjkfdhsjkfadhsfkds fdshfjkldsh fjkldsh fdshfdshfdsfhsfdsfh sf ewf g iuf herjkdsjkjvdhsvdshvdsv dshv ds vads vds hvsdvjkds vds hviuds  vhv disu ghdisuv g"
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.red
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    TextView(isEditable: .constant(false), text:  .constant(textForTextView), textStyle:$textStyle, didStartEditing: .constant(false),placeHolderText:"")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 300)
                }
                HStack {
                    Button("Top") {
                    }
                    Button("Middle") {
                    }
                    Button("Bottom") {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry For late reply. I have checked your code and it's working fine. But I stuck at the last point if I set textview scrolling off. Because current 2 scrolling enabled on screen one id scrollview and the second one is textview scrolling. Can you please help me. How to disable textview scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that adds auto-resizing of the TextView based on the amount of text shown:

[image]

And here is the code for that:

```
class myTextObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem."
}

struct TextviewWithScrollview: View {
    @State private var textStyle = UIFont.TextStyle.body
    
    @StateObject var textForView = myTextObject()
    @State private var textViewSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ScrollView {

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        TextView(
                            isEditable: .constant(false),
                            text: $textForView.text,
                            textStyle: $textStyle,
                            didStartEditing: .constant(false),
                            placeHolderText: "",
                            textViewSize: $textViewSize
                        )
                        .frame(minHeight: 30, idealHeight: min(textViewSize.height, geo.size.height), maxHeight: geo.size.height)
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Button("Top") {
                        }
                        Button("Middle") {
                            self.$textForView.text.wrappedValue += "\n-- a new line --"
                        }
                        Button("Bottom") {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isEditable:Bool
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle
    @Binding var didStartEditing: Bool
    var placeHolderText: String = ""
    
    @Binding var textViewSize: CGSize
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        textView.dataDetectorTypes = .all
        textView.textColor = .gray
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            textViewSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.textContainer.size)
        }
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let newContentSize = uiView.sizeThatFits(uiView.textContainer.size)
            context.coordinator.parent.$textViewSize.wrappedValue = newContentSize
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: TextView
        
        init(parent: TextView)  {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.$text.wrappedValue = textView.text
                
                let newContentSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.textContainer.size)
                self.parent.$textViewSize.wrappedValue = newContentSize
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry For late reply. I have checked your code and it's working fine. But I stuck at the last point if I set textview scrolling off. Because current 2 scrolling enabled on screen one is scrollview and the second one is textview scrolling. Can you please help me. How to disable textview scrolling.

Comment: Not sure what you would like to accomplish? In the second implementation I posted the text view is auto-sizing, so there is never any scrolling in the text view happening as long as the text view fits within the visible screen area of the scroll view. The moment you put more text in, the text view offers scrolling behaviour. You can change the height until which text view is not scrolling by changing the geo.size.height in the .frame modifier. BTW, when I set textView.isScrollEnabled = false the ScrollView behaves differently. I have not looked into why that is.